# integral of a product of functions being $0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, continuity

Suppose we have a continuous function $f$ on $[a,b]$ such that for all integrable functions $g$ such that $\int_{[a,b]}g=0$, $\int_{[a,b]}fg=0 $.

Show that $f$ must be constant.

Well, it's clear this holds for constant functions. In my attempt, I assumed $f$ was not constant, and came up with the fact that $\int_{[a,b]}g(f-k) =0$ for all integers $k$.

How can I couple this with the fact that $f$ must have a small interval with nonzero integral to get the result? It seems like I am close...

Any thoughts/other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your result $\int g(f-k) = 0$ and pick $k = \frac{\int f}{b-a}$.

Then $\int f-k =0$ so we can take $g=f-k$ which gives
$$ \int (f-k)^2 =0$$

which imples that $f$ is constant.

Comment: but that choice of $k$ is not an integer

Comment: Why does $k$ have to be an integer? The result $\int g(f-k) = 0$ holds for all $k$.

Comment: To clarify: $\int g = 0 \to \int kg = 0$ for all $k$ so $\int g(f-k) = \int gf - \int kg = 0$

Comment: Oh, of course. I only doubted because I arrived at that conclusion differently.

Answer (score 2):

If $f_{av}$ is the average of $f$ and $g_{av}$ the average of $g$, then for any $g$,
$$
\int (f-f_{av})g=\int (f-f_{av})[(g-g_{av})+g_{av}]=\int f(g-g_{av}) - \int f_{av}(g-g_{av})+\int (f-f_{av}) g_{av}=0-0+0=0,
$$
so $f-f_{av}$ must be zero.

Comment: Thanks alot for the response!

Comment: i don't actually see why you conclude $f-f_{av}=0$

Comment: If $\int (f-f_{av}) g=0$ for any $g$ then this is both well-known and can be checked by substituting $g=(f-f_{av})$ as in Winther's shorter reply.